# Problem in Closing Exe

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, 
I am using form1 as homescreen,.. while running exe from Debug folder, form1.exe appears in Process tab in task manager,...

The problem is:
Through form1 at runtime, i may create more instances of form1
while trying to close particular instance, the instances closed,.. but still exe appears in task manager.

what i found:
If i close the instances in the order what we created,.. all exe closes correctly,.. but if close the 4th instance and then 3rd instance,.. exe remains in task manager. (instead of 3rd and then 4th instance)

I also used Application.Exit() 
but still the Exe remains in taskmanager,......

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? What version of C#, .Net etc.? I just tried this and can't replicate what you describe at all.

Comment: @chandru: 1) There's no such thing as "C#.NET". It's just C#. 2) Tags are a way to categorize questions. The tags are not a place to repeat the title!

Comment: @chandruswami did you ever manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove the .exe from the processes tab, you can probably use Environment.Exit(exitcode). But it does a forced exit on your app.